# pivot table and percentage comparison between columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm new to using pivot tables with sql and have been stuck on this particular issue that I'm hoping someone can help.  My script returns a list of assignments and counts the assignments for each year.  I would like to add a column that has the percentage increase or decrease change from the previous year.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [year_time], [assignment_code], [assignment_desc]
FROM raw_teacher
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(assignment_code)
    FOR [year_time] IN ([2012], [2011], [2010], [2009], [2008])
) as pvt
```

Current Output:

[image]

Desired output...
[image]

Comment: Frankly, I would see that last bit as a job for the front-end (perhaps Excel as your illustration suggests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the calculation directly:

```
with cte as (
     SELECT *
     FROM
     (
     SELECT [year_time], [assignment_code], [assignment_desc]
     FROM raw_teacher
     ) AS source
     PIVOT
     (
         COUNT(assignment_code)
         FOR [year_time] IN ([2012], [2011], [2010], [2009], [2008])
     ) as pvt
    )
select assignment_desc, [2012], [2012]/[2011], [2011], [2011]/[2010],
                        [2010], [2010]/[2009], [2009], [2009]/[2008], [2008]
from cte
```

If the values can be 0, then you'll want to check for that:

```
select asignment_desc,
       [2012], (case when [2011] <> 0 then [2012]/[2011] end),
       [2011], (case when [2010] <> 0 then [2011]/[2010] end),
       . . .
from cte
```

Comment: Gordon the script above works thank you.  If Im wanting the results in decimal format how do I convert.

Comment: @Tone . . . There are several ways.  One is to cast to a format such as `decimal(10, 2)`.